# Transform a JsonProperty in another Type based on the Property value

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this `JsonProperty` defined in my object to serialize to JSON:

```cs
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "client_state")]
public Boolean IsRunning { get; set; }
```

What I want to achieve is to transform the JSON "client_state" so that the JSON property will be a string containing the text "isrunning" when the `IsRunning` property is true and "notrunning" when the `IsRunning` property is false.
How can I define this transformation during JSON serialization?

Comment: You need a custom `JsonConverter`. See [custom serializer for just one property in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18521970/215552)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom serializer for just one property in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521970/custom-serializer-for-just-one-property-in-json-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an intermediate property to perform the serialization and ignore the original one

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "client_state")]
public string ClientState => IsRunning ? "isrunning" : "notrunning";

[JsonIgnore]
public Boolean IsRunning { get; set; }
```