# Json.NET - Serialize object but don't fully serialize a property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing objects to json using Json.NET. However, certain properties of my object are objects themselves that contain quite a lot of additional information, so my json output is very cluttered and hard to interpret. Ideally, I would like to show that these specific properties exist (show the object type) but without fully serializing them.

For example, instead of:

```
{
    "sport": "football",
    "popular": true,
    "rules": [
        {
            "highSchool": 
            {
                ...
            }
        },
        {
            "college":
            {
                ...
            }
        },
        {
            "nfl":
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to show:

```
{
    "sport": "football",
    "popular": true,
    "rules": {Sports.Football.Rules}
}
```

Is this possible? I have tried using `[JsonIgnore]` in my `Rules` class for the `rules` property, but this ignores the `rules` property entirely instead of including but not serializing the property's object. I also read that `[JsonProperty]` and `[JsonIgnore]` are static and cannot be conditionally set, so that seems to rule out an alternative approach of selectively serializing the property (such as if `Verbose` is provided).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom serializer for just one property in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521970/custom-serializer-for-just-one-property-in-json-net)

Comment: You could do what you'd like to by using a custom serializer for the property as described in the above post. However, by serializing `rules` to simply the name of the type, you probably wouldn't have any way to deserialize the json

Comment: I would use the `ToStringConverter` from [How to make JSON.Net serializer to call ToString() when serializing a particular type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22354867/10263).  You can mark any properties you want with `[JsonConverter(typeof(ToStringConverter))]` to get them to use the converter.  The default implementation of `ToString()` will write out the type name for a class.  If you want a different output, you can override `ToString()` to make it write whatever string value you want.